# WSO2 ESB Management Console (Web Interface) forgotten password

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I've forgotten my WSO2 ESB Web User interface password.
How can i reset my password?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about the carbon console. If so you should be able to see and/or change the password under "/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml"

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Configuring+user-mgt.xml

**Edit**

Ok seems as the above method only reveals the admin password at initial start up. You should however be able to change the password with [this](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2torial-changing-passwords-in-wso2) method, it has a link in it linking to the official wso2 documentation regarding the matter.

Comment: What doesn't work? You can't open the file? The password in it doesn't work?